# Cannot read the property 'addEventListener' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, typeerror

I was trying to make an animation when you hover, and if you stop hovering force the animation to finish, but the problem is that the JavaScript code tells me that there is an error.

When I change `i <= elements.length;` to `i < elements.length;` it doesn't give me the error, but the animation is not working.

```js
// FOOTER MAIL ANIMATION
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName(".mail");

for (let i = 0; i <= elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener("animationend", function (e) {
    elements[i].classList.remove("animated");
  });

  elements[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function (e) {
    elements[i].classList.add("animated");
  });
}
```

```css
.mail {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #008aff;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mail a {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.mail i {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  bottom: -3.5px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.mail.animated i {
  animation: correo 1s;
}

@keyframes correo {
  20% {
    transform: translate(-10px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(100px);
  }
  81% {
    transform: translate(0, -50px);
  }
}
```

```html
          <button class="mail">
            <a href="mailto:" class="titulo">Enviar email <i class="far fa-envelope"></i></a>
          </button>
            <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/399548db15.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: It's a typo, remove the period before mail in `getElementsByClassName` and in your for loop, use `<` with no equal sign.

Comment: The reason you getting an error when using `i <= elements.length;` is that you should use `i <= elements.length -1;` instead. Imagine your array has 3 elements so `elements.length` would return 3. And the value of `i` in the last loop would be `3` which is an invalid index for `elements` because `elements[3]` does not exist (would be undefined). In Javascript indices start at zero.

Answer (score 1):

When using `getElementsByClassName`, you don't need to use a dot.

What you currently have:

```
document.getElementsByClassName(".mail");
```

What it should be:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("mail");
```

You only need the dot when using `querySelector`

Comment: i didn't realize it, it works now but tells me there's still an error, i changed the `i <= elements`  to a `i < elements` and now works an no error, thanks!!!